# How to add a menu bar to a Tk() container in python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, window, menubar

I am trying to design a window with a menu bar on top with the controls `Add Client`,`Print Client Lists` and `Exit`. I have imported all required elements from the tkinter library and created a new container for the controls but am getting this error when I try to add the first menu item to the menu bar `for k, v in cnf.items():AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'`

**Code**

```
##this is the order.py file responsible for drawing
##the window and ui
from tkinter import *
from Business import *

def add_user():
    print("hello world")
##create a container to hold the components inside the frame
myframe=Tk()
##create the menu bar
menub=Menu(myframe,background='#111', foreground='#111')
##the line below has a bug, i havwe defined the command and the name
menub.add_command('Add Client',command=myframe.quit)
myframe.config(menu=menub)
myframe.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [mre].

Comment: @martineau, paste the code inside Visual Studio and run, it will reproduce the error am getting

Comment: I don't use Visual Studio, but that does not matter — there's no `for k, v in cnf.items():`  (or something similar) statement in your code which is what I was talking about.

Comment: @martineau, its the error am getting from the `python.exe` command line that shows up when you run python code, the other error is here `self.add('command', cnf or kw)`

Comment: Is this enough to help debug  `File "c:\users\timothyfarcry5\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Banking\Banking\Banking.py", line 12, in <module>
    menub.add_command('Add Client',command=myframe.quit)`

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: am open to new code than achieve what I want, the code I posted is what I tried

Comment: a window  with a menu bar on top as simple as that, I know that Tk() is the class for drawing window in python

Comment: @martineau, those tutorials are what I tried before coming to SO to post

Comment: In that case you should be able to post the code you tried that didn't work (and explain what happened instead). See [Python - Tkinter Menu](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_menu.htm) which also has an example.

Comment: @martineau, checking the link out

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should better read tutorials - you have to use `label=...`

```
menub.add_command(label='Add Client', command=myframe.quit)
```

---

If you don't use `label=` then it assigns text to first variable in function's definition - `cnf=...` - and this variable expects `dictionary` and it doesn't know what to do with string `'Add Client'`. You can even see `cnf.items()` in error message.

---

Minimal working example:

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---

def add_user():
    print("hello world")
    
# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

menu = tk.Menu(root)
menu.add_command(label='Add Client', command=add_user)
menu.add_command(label='Exit', command=root.destroy)  # `root.quit` may not close window in some situations

root.config(menu=menu)

root.mainloop()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)